# how to write a simple http intercept?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Can somebody explain what is wrong with the following?

```dart
void main() {
  var intercept = new HttpInterceptor();
  intercept.response = (HttpResponse response) => print('we have a response');
  Injector injector = ngBootstrap(module: new MyModule());
  var interceptors = injector.get(HttpInterceptors);
  interceptors.add(intercept);
}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

And here is how I do an http request (from inside a directive):

```dart
@NgDirective(
  selector: '.my-selector')
class MyDirective implements NgAttachAware {
  @NgOneWay('id')
  String id;
  Element self;
  MyDirective(Element el) {
    self = el;
  }
  void attach() {
    final String _urlBase = 'http://www.some-site.com/';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', _urlBase + id);
    req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // do something useful
      } else {
        print('download failed');
      }
    });
    req.send();
  }
}
```

Requests return successfully but the interceptor never fires. Why?

Comment: Could you be a bit more spcific as to what, if any, error messages or undesired behavior you're seeing?

Comment: it doesn't get called

Comment: Your code looks ok. Could you share how you are calling Http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the AngularDart built-in service "Http" and not the dart:html HttpRequest class.
The HttpInterceptors only work on when using that service which wraps the HttpRequest class.

In other words, inject Http in the directive´s constructor:

```dart
MyDirective(Element el, Http http) {
  self = el;
  this._http = http;
}
```

Comment: after further testing, it looks as if any kind of interceptor (i.e. request or response) needs to return either the "HttpResponseConfig" object or the "HttpResponse object", i.e.

GOOD
intercept.response = (HttpResponse response) {
  print('responding...');
  return response;
};"

BAD
intercept.response = (HttpResponse response) => print('responding');