# Can't get HttpInterceptors to work

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

I'm probably missing something dumb but I cannot get the HttpInterceptor to work. Based on a couple of examples ([x](https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/blob/871ef2f8d2b6d91f7ea8f56cdb80b099d01dcfb8/lib/global_http_interceptors.dart) [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913222/configuring-angulardart-modules) [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890860/how-to-write-a-simple-http-intercept)) and the API reference I wrote this code that doesn't seem to do anything when a new page is routed to.

```dart
Injector inj = applicationFactory().addModule(new MyClient()).run();
RequestInterceptor intercept = (HttpResponseConfig res) => print("TEST");
inj.get(HttpInterceptors).add(
    new HttpInterceptor()..request = intercept
);
```

Comment: Your code looks ok.  How are your routing to new pages?  Do you see HTTP requests being sent to the server?

Comment: Did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890860/how-to-write-a-simple-http-intercept/23141450#23141450